# Arrow functions not transpiled

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I try to use Typescript on new project, but arrow functions is not transpiled.

My typescript config :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2015", "es2017", "es2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

In my bundle compiled, i see `=>` but no `function` :/

But, i've add target to ES5, so typescript do transpile arrow function to function ? I don't really understand why it don't work :(

Any one can help me ?

Thank you guyz !